# svn/svnserve problems with commits

Tags: repository, svn

I've installed SVN on my local machine and I've got a problem. I want to commit some files to my repository. I used svnadmin to create and configured entire svn so it works to some point. Now, I want, e.g. to commit files from anywhere to my repo, but I keep getting errors like : This directory is not under version control. So I tried to commit files which were created in the repository manually (what's the point in doing that?) and I did it. But it works only if I write:

```
svn checkout file:///[here goes my repo's path]/test
```

The output is e.g.

```
checked out revision 7
```

But when I type:

```
svn checkout svn://127.0.0.1/test
```

The output goes like nothing ever happened:

```
Checked out revision 0
```

Any ideas how to really commit files to a server? I've been trying putting paths/urls as an argument for svn commit, like hundred times and I have no more ideas how to fix it, please help :/

Answer (score 0):

> commit files from anywhere to my repo

You can not commit from anywhere, you can commit only from working Copy of this repository (created by `svn co`)

In order to have `svn checkout svn://` results you must have running and properly configured svnserve daemon, file file:/// access doesn't require any additional steps. Do you have svnserve running on your box? Test it with `svn ls svn://127.0.0.1/test`